# Cannot make my dropdown content align with my search bar when my search bar is centered. What can I do?

Tags: html, css

Search bar is meant to sit in the center of this table navbar. obviously I havent included a lot of the code so if anybody wants to see all of my code please ask as I'm really struggling with this. This works however the dropdown content seems to left align in it's td elemnt. Please help

This is the html

```
<table class="navbar-table">
    <tr>
        <!-- <td style= "margin: 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px"><span class="sidenav_btn">&#9776;  Menu</span></td> -->

      <td style= "margin: 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px; width:33.33%; float: left;">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <span class="dropbtn">&#9776;  Menu</span>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="../leaderboard.html">Leaderboard</a>
            <a href="../about_us.html">About Us</a>
            <a class="active" href="slide1.html">Slides</a>
            <a style=" display: none;" id= "profile-button-text" href= "../profile/achievements.html" >Profile</a>
            <a style= "background-color: #ab727a; display: none;" id= "logout-button-text">Log Out</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>

        <td class= "search_bar_td">
          <div class="dropdown-search">
            <input autocomplete="off" class= "search_bar" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
            <div class="dropdown-search-content">
              <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
              <a href="../leaderboard.html">Leaderboard</a>
              <a href="../about_us.html">About Us</a>
              <a class="active" href="slide1.html">Slides</a>
              <a style=" display: none;" id= "profile-button-text" href= "../profile/achievements.html" >Profile</a>
              <a style= "background-color: #ab727a; display: none;" id= "logout-button-text">Log Out</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>


      <td style= "margin: 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px; width:33.33%;">
        <ul style= "margin: 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px;">
        <li class="navbar-logsin" id= "signup-button" style=" background-color: #72ab99">
          <a class= "topnav_a" id= "signup-button-text">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-logsin" id= "login-button" style=" background-color: #73a872">
          <a class= "topnav_a" id= "login-button-text">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

This is the css

```
.search_bar {
  width: 240px;
  float: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: none;
}

.search_bar_td {
   float: center; 
   width: 33.33%;
   margin: 6px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px;
}




.dropdown-search {
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  float: center;
  display:block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-search-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  max-height:150px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  z-index: 1;
  float: center;
  margin: 6px 0px;
}


.search_bar:focus + .dropdown-search-content {
  height: auto;
  width: 240px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout, wee are not in the last century anymore. Also make sure to use valid css, float center does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As @cloned stated you do not need to use tables at all. I would suggest using flexbox for this type of thing. Here is a fiddle of a basic nav bar with a search input and everything aligned center. To fix your issue put the dropdown issue I simply positioned the search dropdown absolute relative to the parent wrapper

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
 nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
 nav .search {
  width: 30%;
   position: relative;
}

.search ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" name="" id="searc-bar">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```